# angularjs PATCH method 404 response

Tags: angularjs, restangular

*WORK AROUND IS AT THE BOTTOM*

**Original problem**

There are question like this all over the web and none of them really have answer for me. I can't get an http PATCH operation to work using angular to save my life. I've implemented $http, with shortcut $http.patch and without using the config object method:PATCH. I've used $resource by adding a custom method. And I've implemented Restangular using their patch and I'm getting the same error. I have the correct Content-Type as suggested in other posts. I think it's safe to say at this point, it's something I'm missing. I'm getting the same "404" message via postman when trying to patch. I can PUT, GET, POST, and DELETE, but not PATCH.

In the following images you can see that the resource exists for GET. But when trying to patch I get 404. Browsing to that endpoint shows the record. Which is stored in Mongodb.

[image: successful GET for resource]

[image: failed PATCH on resource]

Here's some code snippets:

Resangular GET:

```
        var corporiumRecord = Restangular.one('corporium-mgmnts', $scope.uuid);
        corporiumRecord.get().then(function(res) {
            console.log(res)
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Restangular failed: ', err)
        });
```

Restangular Patch:

```
            var data = {
                corporiumId: $scope.newBlock
            };

            var corporiumRecord = Restangular.one('corporium-mgmnts', $scope.uuid);
            corporiumRecord.patch(data).then(function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('Restangular failed: ', err)
            });
```

$http attempt using config object:

controller code:

```
                httpCorporiumSrv.updateCorporiumId('/corporium-mgmnts/' + $scope.params.id, data)
                    .then(handleUpdateSuccess)
                    .catch(handleUpdateError);
```

service code, tried forcing the content-type header but got same result
with or without it:

```
function updateCorporiumId(url, data)  {
        return $http({
            method: 'PATCH',
            url: url,
            data: angular.toJson(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            }
            //transformRequest: transformUpdateData
        })
            .then(handleUpdateSuccess)
            .catch(handleUpdateErrors);
    }
```

Using the .patch shortcut:

```
function updateCorporiumId(url, data)  {
        return $http.patch(url, data, {
            transformRequest: transformUpdateData
        })
            .then(handleUpdateSuccess)
            .catch(handleUpdateErrors);
    }
```

Thing is I've tried this every which way I know how. I don't even know how to start debugging any more. I'm just getting 404 on a resource that does exist. Any suggestions on what might be happening to my request would be great.

---

**Resolution:**

For anyone having this issue, if you could post the fix or what's going on here to this point or PM me that would be awesome I'd like to know. I ended up just using PUT to fix this.

Quick Restangular solution:

Build the url template for findByOne like function using Restangular.one(url, _id) where '_id', is the id of the resource you're looking for. .get() goes out and finds that one resource by said id, which you can populate dynamically however you like. Once you have the one resource with GET copy it with Restangular.copy() which is different from angular.copy as it doesn't bind 'this' to the new object. Change what needs to be changed or added in the new object and then perform a .put() on it.

```
 var corporiumRecord = Restangular.one('corporium-mgmnts', $scope.uuid);
                    corporiumRecord.get().then(function(res) {
                        var update = Restangular.copy(res);
                        // update date corporiumId
                        update.corporiumId = $scope.newBlock;
                       // submit new doc with altered value
                        update.put().then(function() {
                            console.log('updated')
                        });
                        console.log(update)
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log('Restangular failed: ', err)
                    });
```

Also because mongo uses _id and Restangular uses id you have to add this to your module

```
angular.module('corporium-mgmnts').config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setMethodOverriders(['put', 'patch']);
    // setRestangularFields is required for mongodb
    RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
        id: "_id"
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the server endpoint? Are you sure that the PATCH method is supported by your endpoint?

Comment: Mongoose is hosting the endpoint for this Node app. I have a hateoas api written in nodejs but I'm not using it right now, I'm trying to get angular to work as the front end might be decoupled and hosted with java at some point. Might I have falsely assumed that mongoose doesn't allow patch? I thought it would.

Comment: **Mongoose** cannot be the endpoint (server) as it is an `orm`. Why do you need the PATCH method for?

Comment: Ok well, maybe i'm misunderstanding what you want to know. I need the patch method for atomic updates? If you're asking what the physical server is it's just my laptop right now all local.

Comment: It's too much of a hassle I don't know what's going on with it. I solved it with put anyway I'll post the code above for anyone who doesn't know what to do in this situation. I was using PATCH in a previous project and It was great for what I needed but it's no big deal. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well the PATCH method can be quite project dependent. If you had the patch method available in one API it might not be available in an other. Also the PATCH method doesn't promise to do atomic updates. It's likely that if you used the PATCH method in a different project, someone implemented it himself.